# Laravel problem where two users using the same machine, same browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

1.User 1 logs in the domain.

2.User 1 changes some data without saving it.

3.User 2 logs in the domain in a separate tab.

4.User 1 switches back to his tab and saves the data.

5.User 1 actually saved the data into User 2!!

is there any inbuilt mechanism in laravel to handel this?

What will be the efficent method to handel it?

Comment: how do you authenticate the users ?

Comment: I use auth for authenticating users ....

Comment: Yes, there is. Laravel provides a really good way of **Authorizing** user. Please go through https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization